# Wine performance counters

Tags: c#, linux, wine

В wine есть PerformanceCounters?
Выполняю следующий код

```
 var categories =  PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
 Console.WriteLine($"Founded {categories.Length} categories");
```

Получаю вывод

```
Founded 0 categories
```

Есть какой-то способ включить или настроить счётчики производительности в wine?

Update:

Всем спасибо за комментарии, в общих чертах понял.  Мы находимся в состоянии портирования приложения с винды (.net Framework 4.7.2) на кроссплатформу, с промежуточным этапом в виде wine, потому выясняю, какие части приложения придется переделывать, а какие будут работать под wine неизменно. В итоге планируем .net 5, но кодовая база крайне большая и быстро перейти не получится.

Comment: А зачем они в Wine? Этот эмулятор не для инженерного софта. Соберите приложение под Linux, и будут вам счетчики.

Comment: Приложение какого типа, вернее, под какой фреймворк? .NET FW под Винду? Нет ли возможности пересобрать под .NET 5 (или Core)?

Comment: [EventCounters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters) - кроссплатформенные счётчики производительности

Comment: Performance Counters - это сущности операционной системы. Wine эмулирует лишь часть ОС. Очевидно, что Виндовые счётчики там не сделаны. Поэтому самое правильное решение - использовать кроссплатформенные счётчики Event Counters.